# VBA MS access functions

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

Following function is for evaluating dates called by procedure CheckEventDataIntegrity. This does only for events but now I want to add partnumber along with event type. Means it should evaluate dates with event and partnumber.How Can I do this??

```
'-----------------------------
'-----------------------------
' Function : EvaluateDates
' Purpose   : flags date sequencing errors, called by CheckEventDataIntegrity
'-----------------------------
Private Function EvaluateDates(et As String)
Dim varx As Variant
On Error GoTo EvaluateDates_Error

    varx = DLookup("[EventDate]", "tblEventLog", "[TrackingNumber] = '" & Me!TrackingNumber & "' And [EventTypeSelected] = '" & et & "'")

    If IsNull(varx) Then ' predecessor event does not exist
        displayMsgBox = _
            MsgBox("No '" & et & "' event has been Recorded. Please correct.", _
            vbCritical)
        EvaluateDates = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    If varx > Me!EventDate Then ' predecessor event exists but date is after date being posted
        displayMsgBox = _
            MsgBox("Chronological Error. Previously posted '" & et & "' event has date stamp that is later than date stamp of completion event you are now attempting to post. Please verify date of event you are now posting. If it is correct than contact admin.", _
            vbCritical)
        EvaluateDates = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    EvaluateDates = True

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function
EvaluateDates_Error:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure EvaluateDates of VBA Document Form_frmEventLog_Input"
End Function
```

called by CheckEventDataIntegrity procedure as follows:

'-----------------------------
'-----------------------------
' Procedure : CheckEventDataIntegrity
' Purpose   : verifies process logic is being followed, this checks for sequencing
'-----------------------------
Function CheckEventDataIntegrity(fl1 As Boolean)
On Error GoTo CheckEventDataIntegrity_Error

```
Do While fl1 = True
```

'event type #1a
          If Me!EventTypeSelected = "1a  Assign - To Checker Queue" Then
           If EvaluateDates("1    Receive NEW from Detailer") = False Then ' wrapper has not been assigned to Checker
               CheckEventDataIntegrity = False
               Exit Function
               Else
                '  CheckEventDataIntegrity = True
               Exit Do
                   End If
                   End If
'event type #2
        If Me!EventTypeSelected = "2    ReV - Assignment" Then
        If EvaluateDates("1    Receive NEW from Detailer") = False Then ' wrapper has not been assigned to reviewer
                CheckEventDataIntegrity = False
                Exit Function
                Else
                Exit Do
           End If
           End If

### ----

### ------

### -----

---

fl1 = False
    Loop
    'nothing failed test
    CheckEventDataIntegrity = True

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function
CheckEventDataIntegrity_Error:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CheckEventDataIntegrity of VBA Document Form_frmEventLog_Input"
End Function

I can add partnumber as follows in the evaluatedates function:

```
Private Function EvaluateDates(et As String, pn As String)
    varx = DLookup("[EventDate]", "tblEventLog", "[TrackingNumber] = '" & Me!TrackingNumber & "' And [EventTypeSelected] = '" & et & "' And [PartNumber] = '" & Pn & "'")
```

But how can I implement it in the CheckEventDataIntegrity procedure??

Comment: I am gonna have nightmares tonight about this code from those eventtype strings alone.

Comment: The second code snippet is incomplete as there is no Loop for the Exit Do to apply to. We can't really answer your question without the full code context.

Comment: Updated with the loop....please check out

Comment: This isn't really a question about a specific issue, with a simplified example to showcase the problem.  It is more about trying to get someone else to fix your production code.

Comment: If you want me to look at your code, at the very least learn how to format it. I'm not bothering to format it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am learning VBA, working on my first project.

I got an answer for this.

Comment: Well, good for you. If you want to contribute to SO and make it better, perhaps you would be kind enough to post an explanation of what worked, so as to help anyone else encountering the same problem.